# What does the ":" mean when it is the leading of a style in a css file?

Tags: css

What is this item called ":" and what is it doing in the css declaration?

e.g.

```
:fooBar { <-- What is the : used for?
  with: 100%
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: Thank you very much. I found exactly what I am seeing in the css under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()

Answer (score 1):

They are called Pseudo-classes (:) and Pseudo-elements (::) if suffixed with a CSS selector.

Some times a CSS selector itself can start with an `:` (`:host`). This is still called a Pseudo-class and it is used to select shadow DOM.

### :host()

This is used to select a an element inside the shadow DOM.

### :host-context()

This is used to select the host or the parent of the shadow DOM

Comment: In regards to the Shadow DOM, are they meaning non visible DOM elements (things hidden)? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

Answer (score -1):

`:` does not come alone. The selector you used as an example is also incorrect. `:` is used to select elements that have a specific property like the following selector:

```
input:disabled
```

The example above selects inactive inputs

Comment: So in CSS we should never see anything in the file that starts only with ":"?  I ask because this project I'm on has some entries with that as entries. Many things are poorly formatted and done herein the file but I have never seen : lead a definition before. I've seen as you pointed out the format of things such as "a:hover"

Comment: ": Does not come alone" - That's not true. For example, `:root`, `:disabled`, `:not(a)`, etc.

Comment: Also, `input:disabled` selects disabled inputs, not inactive ones. `input:not(:active)` selects inactive inputs.